# Lotus Notes 8.5 Default Inbox

Tags: lotus-notes

When I close my email it is showing the inbox, but when I open it the next time it opens into one of the folders not the inbox.  How do I get it upon opening to do so in the inbox and not a folder?

Answer (score 0):

File -> Preferences, 
Basic Notes Client Configuration
Additional Options
Retain View Column Sorting

Hope this helps.

http://twitpic.com/e3w8qk